# How to set-up webhook endpoint so that it can accept https requests?

Tags: node.js, apache, webhooks, messenger

I am trying to set-up a Messenger Webhook Endpoint. The Webhook is written with node.js.
The Endpoint is configured to listen for requests on its default port or Port `1337` if there is no default.

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 1337)
```

The issue is that my server cannot validate the Callback URL `https://example.com/webhook` request coming from Messenger. Here is the screenshot:[image]

How do I re-direct the requests coming over https to the webhook endpoint.

(I am using Apache2 as my HTTP server running on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)

I am following this documentation for my setup: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/webhook-setup/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be resolved using **SSL Termination with Apache**. You basically have it act as a reverse proxy that forwards anything on `https://example.com/webhook` to `http://localhost:1337/webhook`.

So there's two parts to this. The NodeJS will listen on localhost:1337 and the  Apache translating from public HTTPS and proxying that to NodeJS.

This tutorial by DigitalOcean is very helpful for setting up Webhooks in a Apache Server:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy-with-mod_proxy-on-ubuntu-16-04

Also, this [ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1056450/how-to-do-ssl-termination-on-apache-tomcat) helped with configuring VirtualHosts file.

Comment: Looks like the poster answered their own question. The question is very general and the answer is very specific for NodeJS and Apache. You should add some context to the question if you just answer for NodeJs and Apache. Webhook could be anything like Java or Nginx.